# Using a Public Property AND a Public Field

Tags: object-oriented, .net

Where I work, using Properties are discouraged. We have code generation tools to "speed things up". All object data ends up being Public fields. If you request properties anyway, you get something like this:

```
Public sFoo as String

Public Property Foo as String
  Get
    Return sFoo
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value as String)
    sFoo = value
  End Set
End Property
```

I can't think of a reasonable argument to do this. Are there any good reasons to use both a Public Property with a Public Field?

Comment: no. change the code generator to generate Public string Foo { get; set; } instead

Comment: Is there any evidence that it speeds things up? Is there any evidence that the code when executed is any different? Why are you asking this; you clearly already know this is dumb. The burden of proof should be on the person doing this practice. If they can't justify it and you can't get them to change, then I'd recommend a new job!

Comment: Why a downvote? It's the author's fault that in his company, there are stupid guidelines.

Comment: Possibly the field was meant to be private and returned by the Property. Maybe somebody kind of knew the concept but messed up big time. Using private field exposed as public property is good codding practice and used even if you don't see it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### No.

There's no good reason for this.  It:

1. Confuses other programmers by doing something that makes no sense,
2. Exposes the innards of your class unnecessarily,
3. Provides two entry points for the same thing,
4. ??

Use [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) instead.

Comment: Is the downvoter seriously advocating the use of public properties AND fields at the same time?  I'm getting a little tired of having a single downvote on every answer I post... If you have enough time to follow me around downvoting my answers, you need a new hobby.

Comment: Somebody is stalking you Robert. Not me cause this is definitely the correct answer and the question by the OP has me stunned. Years of learning and writing it never even crossed my mind to do such a thing..

Comment: I've also heard it argued by some that using properties incurs a performance penalty over directly accessing fields, but in general that isn't true.  In every version of the CLR I've ever encountered, simple properties like this one are almost always inlined by the optimizer, so even that isn't a realistic concern.

Answer (score 2):

One of the fundemental object oriented principles is called Encapsulation. It says that each object should protect it's data from outside modification.

This is done by making all fields private and if possible also make all property setters private. Instead you have to introduce behaviour by adding methods which is used to modify state.

What you are doing is very wrong. In essence it's just functional programming where all classes are only data containers or a way of grouping methods togehter. The former is an anti pattern called [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

The problem with that is that the business logic for every domain model is spread out over several places in your application (i.e. every place where the object is modified). Hence it's hard to find bugs related to your business rules as you have to analyze every place where the object is used, instead of just analyzing the object iself.

I've blogged about this here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any good reasons to use both a Public Property with a Public Field?

In short: **No**, there are no justification for that. The public properties have more business uses than public fields.

Some of the many uses of properties are:

- Properties can validate data before allowing a change
- It can transparently expose data on a class where that data is actually retrieved from some other source, such as a database
- It can take an action when data is changed, such as raising an event, or changing the value of other fields

As already suggested, using auto-properties is another smart way to go with.

More details in [**MSDN - VB.NET properties**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308230)